# Field Update Based on Workflow

Tags: workflow, formula-field

I have one object named "Information" and in that i have 3 field listed below

1. Amount (type - Currency)
2. current(formula-return 0 and 1)
3. balance (type- number)

now here i want to fill the field balance based on the following workflow rule criteria

case:

1) if Amount != 0 and current != 0 then balance = 0
else 1(in any other case)

**[Balance field was not more used in page layout-this field is just used for reference of other field]**

can i do that with the help of one workflow and one or two field update???

Please suggest me so i can complete my task

Thanaks in advance for your support

Answer (score 0):

A workflow with a single field update should do it, since you only want to update balance as far as I understood. This should work whether or not the Amount or Balance is on Layouts.
Did you try it and run into any issues? If so we may need more details.

Comment: yes i have faced issue while based on formula field i am not able to populate the Balance field. Formula filed is based on some date field and return 1 and 0 based upon some formula.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise and describe your issue (either in words or better with a screenshot?) - otherwise it's guesswork...

Comment: Also please paste your formula so we can replicate your scenario in a testing environment.